# How do I send a view model to the controller via ajax which includes form data but not by clicking the submit button

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web App which quotes for products. I am trying to send the view model to the controller via ajax, which will return a view model with a calculated quote total and display it in the partial view.

I am able to send the model to the controller but the model only contains the default values that were loaded into the view and none of the form input values. I feel like i'm missing something really simple here. I've tried a lot of options including serialising the form, which gets the values into the controller but misses the rest of the model.

The code below sends the model to the controller when the function is called (which is what I want) but does not include the values inputted into the form. Is there a way to achieve this or does the whole thing need reworking?

Help me Stack Overflow, you are my only hope.

### Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculateItemQuote(string jsonString)
    {

        BifoldItemViewModel bifoldItemViewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BifoldItemViewModel>(jsonString);

        // Do calculations and return view model to partial view.

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_BifoldItemHeader.cshtml", bifoldItemViewModel);
    }
```

---

### Script

function RefreshHeaderValue() {

```
    var serModel =  '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model))';
          console.log(serModel);
      $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CalculateItemQuote", "Quote")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { jsonString: serModel },
          dataType: 'json',
          traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#bifoldHeaderPartial").html(data);
                $('#bifoldHeaderPartial').show();
            }
        });
    };
```

---

View

```
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="thisBifoldItem.Width"></label>
                    <input asp-for="thisBifoldItem.Width" class="form-control" autocomplete="nay" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="thisBifoldItem.Width" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="thisBifoldItem.Height"></label>
                    <input asp-for="thisBifoldItem.Height" class="form-control" autocomplete="nay" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="thisBifoldItem.Height" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label asp-for="DoorQuantityOptions" class="control-label">How Many Doors?</label>
                    <select asp-for="SelectedDoorQuantity" id="DoorQuantityOptions" class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.DoorQuantityOptions">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

==========
UPDATED SOLUTION==========

Thanks to  kbaccouche for pushing me in the right direction. The following now works

Controller

---

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculateItemQuote(BifoldItemViewModel bifoldItemViewModel)
{

```
        //Do stuff here

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_BifoldItemHeader.cshtml", bifoldItemViewModel);
    }
```

---

Script

---

function RefreshHeaderValue() {

```
      $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CalculateItemQuote", "Quote")',
            type: 'POST',
          data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
          dataType: 'json',
          traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#bifoldHeaderPartial").html(data);
                $('#bifoldHeaderPartial').show();
            }
        });
    };
```

---

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has ModelBinders which will do the JSON conversion for you. So you can have a `BifoldItemViewModel` type parameter to `CalculateItemQuote`. You need to create your own (or update the existing) `serModel` from the inputs on the page.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I'm reading through the ModelBinding documentation at the moment for a solution. I've updated my question with some data from the view. I'm unsure what you mean by updating the serModel from the inputs on the page, do you mean assign them individually like the example from @kbaccouche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a sample application using your code, and I got it to work using standard MVC model binding. Here is the code

**Controller**

```
public class QuoteController : Controller
{
    // POST: Quote/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculateItemQuote(ProductForm model)
    {
        var bifoldItemViewModel = new BifoldItemViewModel();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_BifoldItemHeader.cshtml", bifoldItemViewModel);
    }
}

public class ProductForm
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class BifoldItemViewModel
{

}
```

HTML + Javascript

```
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }

<form>
  <input id="ProductId" name="ProductId" type="text" />
  <input id="Quantity" name="Quantity" type="text" />
  <a id="submitForm" class="btn">Submit</a>
</form>

<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
  <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<div id="bifoldHeaderPartial">

</div>

@section Scripts{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('a#submitForm').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CalculateItemQuote", "Quote")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'ProductId': $('#ProductId').val(),
            'Quantity': $('#Quantity').val()
        },
      dataType: 'json',
      traditional: true,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#bifoldHeaderPartial").html(data);
            $('#bifoldHeaderPartial').show();
        }
    });
  });
 </script>
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, I can see how this works but can't see how to reconcile my model to the ajax request. I've edited my question with some of the view, which shows how the input values bind to the model in the form. Based on your example, should I be assigning these values in the same way?

Comment: To clarify, when submitting the form, it binds all model values correctly, it just doesn't bind the values when i'm posting using the ajax request.

Comment: In this line `var serModel =  '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model))';` you are mixing server side code with client side code. I don't think this is a good practice or that it even works. You can either create manually the object you are sending to the server (like I did) or you can put all your inputs inside a <form> and then in `data` you serialize it like this : **data: $("form").serialize()**

Comment: I've been skirting around the solution for some time now and you've given me the missing piece. I had used data: $("form").serialize()  previously but had the controller parameter as a string for json. I've changed the parameter now to the viewmodel and passing in the serialized form is working. Thank you very much indeed. My headache might go away now!

Comment: Happy to help :)